# How to capture Screenshot in Selenium2 using Java, need to capture popup window with its parent window(Browser) when browser is minimized

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

I tried using `Robot` class with `BufferedImage screenImage = robot.createScreenCapture(screenRect)` but it captures the active Screen only.
Consider the Browser(Firefox) launched by Webdriver is minimized then this method doesn't capture Browser screen, instead it captures the active screen.

Answer (score 0):

Please try below code if you are working with webdriver & java. It will capture the screenshot.

```
File ScreenShot = ((TakesScreenshot) driver)
        .getScreenshotAs(OutputType.FILE);
StringBuilder FileName = new StringBuilder("Path or FolderLocation");
FileName.append(ScreenshotFirstName);
FileName.append("_");
FileName.append(dateFormat.format(date).toString());
FileName.append(".jpeg");
FileUtils.copyFile(ScreenShot, new File(FileName.toString()));
```

It will save the screenshot file with date and time appended to it and to a specific folder location.

Comment: Tried with above suggestion, but this captures only pop-up window that appears on top of Parent Browser(window). The requirement is that both parent browser and popup window should be captured.